# Add custom attribute to the PDFService class Nopcommerce 3.0

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I have a custom attribute that i wish to add to the PDF Invoice in nopcommerce,

i have ran the site with breakpoints in place and can confirm the variable i need to pass is:

"docId"

i have added this code to the PdfService class under the PrintOrderToPdf Method,

```
List<string> values = _productAttributeParser.ParseValues(item.AttributesXml, punchOutDocumentId);

String docID = String.Empty;
if(values.Count > 0)
{
     docID = values.First();
}
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(docID));
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
productsTable.AddCell(cell);
```

from looking at the AttributesXML object i found:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Orders Version="3.00"><Order>

<AttributesXml>&lt;Attributes&gt;&lt;ProductVariantAttribute ID="2147483646"&gt;&lt;ProductVariantAttributeValue&gt;&lt;Value&gt;e8bb4282-43de-4baf-aece-5baed6163e03&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/ProductVariantAttributeValue&gt;&lt;/ProductVariantAttribute&gt;&lt;ProductVariantAttribute ID="2147483645"&gt;&lt;ProductVariantAttributeValue&gt;&lt;Value&gt;D-6DB2F2E5&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/ProductVariantAttributeValue&gt;&lt;/ProductVariantAttribute&gt;&lt;/Attributes&gt;</AttributesXml>
```

i need to show the attribute with the id of:

2147483645 - it starts with D-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to retrieve your attribute.

```
int attributeId = 2147483645;
List<string> values = _productAttributeParser.ParseValues(item.AttributesXml, attributeId);

String docID = String.Empty;
if(values.Count > 0)
{
     docID = values.First();
}
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(docID));
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
productsTable.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Hi @AndyMckenna, i am now getting the errors item and punchoutDocumentId do no exist in the current context

Comment: My example is assuming you are populating those like you did in your sample.

Comment: I have inserted breakpoints and ran the code the variable i need to pass is docId not punchOutDocumentId, i have updated my question

Comment: You probably should have added to rather than replaced your original question, it doesn't make any sense now.  Either way, you need to use the ProductAttributeParser to get the value you are looking for, then add it to the PDF.

Comment: apologies, firing on all cylinders to get this working, now amended question with original answer and added more details

Comment: That edited answer should do it.  Once you know it works you'd probably want to eventually put 2147483645 into a setting or field so you don't have magic numbers hanging out.

Comment: thanks, that attribute id is defined in a key in the web.config: <add key punchOutdocumentId = "2147483645"> or something like that